# Can Mach Number Decrease while Flow Velocity Increases?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow

As in the question statement, I am wondering whether it is possible for Mach number to increase while local flow velocity decreases. I am basing myself on the simple case of an ideal gas, in which:

$$M=\frac{v}{\sqrt{\gamma R T}}\ \tag{*}$$

If we take a diverging supersonic flow ($dA>0, M>1$), for example, the flow velocity must decrease due to the area-velocity relation below:

$$\frac{dv}{v}=\frac{1}{M^2-1}\frac{dA}{A} \ \tag{**}$$

What happens now? Velocity decreased but (from the corresponding temperature relation), the temperature must increase so the Mach number can go either way from equation $(*)$.

Comment: What do you mean by descent ?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey That sounds like it should be an answer, not a comment. Please don't posts answers in the comment section.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134753/59023

Answer (score -1):

Speed of sound increases with air density, so Mach number (the fraction of speed of sound) could decrease with descent (going to a lower altitude), even if airspeed increased.