# What happens when the shockwave is opposing the flow direction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, shock-waves

There is a supersonic flow over a flat plate (assume inviscid--no boundary layer). Suddenly, there is a point blast occurring on the flat plate, generating a semi-spherical shock wave. For the horizontal shock component that is in the direction of the flow, it is just a normal shock-jump relation between the unshocked and shocked flow. But what about the horizontal shock component that is opposite to the direction of the flow? Assume the blast wave itself always has an initial shock front speed higher than the flow.
[image]

Comment: Anything not orthogonal to the surface that moves faster than the speed of sound relative to the medium will generate what is called an oblique shock, in this scenario.  The side that will move anti-parallel to the incident supersonic flow will just have a stronger shock because in the shock rest frame, the incident flow speed will be higher.

Comment: @honeste_vivere would the shock be along the blast front and the speed of shock be the vector sum of flow speed and the original blast front speed?

Comment: Try looking at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/415810/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/271088/59023